# Kentico domain aliasing - Default Path option

Tags: kentico

I'm retrofitting a V9 site with a new 'sub site' This site will have it's own navigation system and IA. My plan, maybe, is to create a new folder in the content tree named 'New Site' and then created all my pages and items within there.

For the domain, i would then create a domain alias, and set the 'Default Alias path' to the 'New Site' folder.

This so far seems clear. Is it possible to have cross site contamination? Ideally, the old and new sites wouldn't mix under a single URL. I'm worried about navigation on the old site ('css list menu') picking up pages from the new site.

Had i know this was the plan, i would have created folders for each site to isolate, but moving to that structure may cause a lot of problems.

Comment: When you say creating folders and adding a sub site are you talking about within the content tree or within the file system?

Comment: Sorry, the content tree. The code structure will stay the same.

Comment: If it's on a separate domain, why not just create a truly separate site within Kentico and manage them that way?

Comment: Because who has a Director title won't buy another license. It doesn't help that i have the new site almost dev complete.

Comment: Technically speaking @MarkHandy if your sites overall have a different look and feel, then the license states you need another license.  So if you have domain.com/site-1 and domain.com/site-2 and they are totally different look and feel, that = new license.  Doesn't matter if they are in the same instance or not.

Comment: I agree. Both of these will share the same look and feel just different audiences. But the Director confirmed with Kentico this could be done. I need to convince them that the extra license costs is cheaper and less risky than me doing a restructure and manual merge. 

People with just enough knowledge to be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers you posted, what I've done in the past is to:

1. create a new page type called Divisions or whatever you'd like.
2. Then create a new page template which doesn't inherit anything from the master page and flag it as a master page. Add the webparts you need on there, specifically a Head HTML webpart with your stylesheets, js, etc.  Because it won't inherit from the main master page.  But if you have a stylesheet assigned in to the site in the Sites application, that will be inherited unless you specify otherwise on the General tab of each new sub site.
3. Back on the page type you just created set the default page template to be the master page you just setup.
4. Add a new sub site/page to the content tree
5. Add new pages under the sub site in the content tree.  Set your navigation path to be `/{0}/%` so it always selects the sub site as the root.

In your other master page you shouldn't need to worry about the other pages, because the parent page won't be visible in the navigation so the children won't show.